# Double tap to zoom doesn't work after upgrading to iOS 13

Tags: html, ios, webkit, wkwebview, double-click

We use WKWebView as browser in our App.

The problem is that double tap to zoom doesn't work when we add a click event listener after upgrading to iOS 13.

You could double tap the text on [this page](http://www.kappabashi.or.jp/en/) to repro. And below is also a minimum web page can repro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            p {
                width: 50px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p class="text">Kappabashi Dougu Street is located in Tokyo's Taito City, along the west side of Asakusa's main entertainment district, and just midway between Ueno and Asakusa.<br> Merchants first began gathering in the Kappabashi area around 1912, selling old tools and a wide range of implements and hardware. Today, one can find almost every kind of restaurant equipment imaginable, including bakery equipment, Japanese, Western, and Chinese tableware, china, laquerware, restaurant equipment, packaging, containers, decorative goods, "fake" food samples, chefs' coats, signs, noren (shop curtains), bamboo wares, baking ingredients, food and beverage ingredients, confectionary wholesalers, Japanese furniture, Western furniture, kitchen equipment, refrigerators and refrigerated showcases, showcases, displays, shop design and construction services, and much more. At 800 meters (nearly a half-mile) in length, and with over 170 shops, this is Japan’s largest shopping street devoted to kitchen implements.</p>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hit this issue too